# wpt how to get been localized list of Fonts?

Tags: wpf

```
  foreach (FontFamily fam in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
            boxFamily.Add(fam);
```

For example, I get font for "FangSong",but i want get for Chinese(仿宋) about font.

please help me ,Thank you.

Comment: You've asked enough questions now that you should have figured out how Stack Overflow works. If you haven't, it's time to learn. You should upvote all of the answers that you think are clear, helpful, or helped to get you onto the right track. You should *accept* the answer (by clicking the hollow checkmark in the left-hand margin) that you found most helpful or that best answered your question. This is how you reward people who take their time to answer your questions and motivate them to continue doing so in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (FontFamily fam in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.FontFamily = new FontFamily(fam.ToString());
                lbl.Content = fam.ToString();
                listBox2.Items.Add(lbl);
            }
```

hope this helps